# Actual best pdf generator for Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I need a pdf generator for Rails 3.1 application.Which one can  you suggest.
I've tried Prawn but it seems me quite not easy for a beginner like me while PdfKit gives me several errors :|

Comment: I like PDFKit and it was very simple to use.  Maybe you should try to get help with the errors.

Comment: But PdfKit I've seen thats its' always capable to convert html in pdf file, but if I want it's capable to open pdf created into Adobe Reader or other pdf reader?

Comment: I've had no problems with opening PDFKit generated documents in PDF readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried both Wicked Pdf and PdfKit but in Development mode they are extremely slows :( Any other suggestions? 
Another (maybe dummy) question: using PdfKit for example, I've seen that it make and open pdf file into web browser,but is there a way to download file into my desktop?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the best fit for you, but I've heard good things about [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)/wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Years ago I worked on a project where PrinceXML was used (still in use by the client) - the $4k/per server license was a bit steep, but it easily paid for itself many times in the time saved. I'm checking this out now as I'd love to have a tool I can use in projects with smaller budgets.